# Java and MS Access

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

The JDBC-ODBC driver doesnot support the same charsets that MS Access using for other then latin characters, thus I cannot read hebrew from the database, which is mostly written in hebrew(a bug report is written [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6345277)
) I tried using [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) for reading from the database but then I've understood that It cannot execute SQL queries is there any alternative for using MS Access and Java?

Answer (score 1):

You could always export the Access database into something else - MySQL, for example, there are a few converters around. Then you could use the MySQL JDBC driver.

Comment: I've done this, but with SQLite as the target (used Jackcess to read the Access database and the SQLite JDBC driver to move the data into the target).  It has the advantage that, like Access, the data is contained in a single file and does not require a server.  The only real downside is that SQLite does not have the variety of datatypes that Access has.  If you need all the complexity of a complete RDBMS without the "server" component, you could go with Derby; but you lose the simplicity of having the whole database in a single file.